# cannot see django server welcome page on firing up the server

Tags: python, django, powershell, pycharm

I am beginning to learn web development with Django, on windows 7. I have installed python 2.7 and django 1.10 for the purpose. I made a sample project from windows powershell, and when i start the django server, as shown below, [starting django server from powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paLHC.png)
when i go to the IP 127.0.0.1:8000/, it does not show me a django welcome page like the one below [django server welcome page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYQnt.png)

All i see is a blank page. I have tried restarting the server many times, but never once, did i see the welcome page. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause of the issue but maybe you want to do the database migration step as the error message suggested. Just run

```
python manage.py migrate
```